# Apache 2.2.21 / apache2handler wrong version?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, linux

I have compile apache 2.2.21 under ubuntu server

from console I can get this:

```
vangelis# /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -v
"Server version: Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) Server built:   Jan  7 2012 12:30:44"
```

from phpinfo() i get this : "Apache Version Apache/2.2.20".

Is this correct? If not how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It is quite possible that you have multiple copies of Apache installed.

To determine the location of the 'default' (i.e. the one that will run if no path is specified), run:

```
which httpd
```

Check your init script to determine the path to version that is setup to start.

If you already have Apache running (likely, since you got the php output), use the following to determine where it is:

```
ps -ef | grep httpd
```

If you do have multiple copies of Apache installed, you should be able to:

- Change your init script to launch the correct one

  - Remove the one you are not using (once you are certain that everything is running well, you may)
- Change your configure parameters, so that you install one over the other